# Find Ultimate Parent using CTE

Tags: sql-server, parent, common-table-expression

I need to run a report in Production Server (SQL server) tomorrow. As I am not very confident with CTE and need quick help, I am putting my query here.

I have a table structure something like this:

**Table:**

```
UnderLyingConstituentMap
{
ParentUnderLyingId int not null,
UnderLyingId int
}
```

One `UnderLying` could be part of more than one `ParentUnderLying`. So it's a many to many relation. 
I am given a set of `UnderLyingId`s and need to find all the ultimate `ParentUnderLyingId`.

There could be some `UnderLying`s which do not have any parent. Then they will not exist in `UnderLyingId` column of this table.

Please help me with a CTE query.

Answer (score 0):

Use Recursive join Like as Below :

```
WITH UserCTE AS (
  SELECT UnderLyingId ,ParentUnderLyingId 
  FROM dbo.UnderLyingConstituentMap 
  WHERE UnderLyingId = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT  UnderLyingId ,ParentUnderLyingId 
  FROM UserCTE AS usr
    INNER JOIN dbo.UnderLyingConstituentMap AS mgr
      ON usr.ParentUnderLyingId = mgr.UnderLyingId 
)
SELECT * FROM UserCTE AS u;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below Query

```
;WITH cte1
as
 (
   SELECT ParentUnderLyingId,UnderLyingId, 0 AS level ,
   convert(varchar(100), '<'+convert(varchar(3),UnderLyingId)+'>') as Visited
   FROM #UnderLyingConstituentMap

   UNION ALL

   SELECT T.ParentUnderLyingId,T.UnderLyingId, level +1 ,
   Convert(varchar(100),Visited +'<'+convert(varchar(3),cte1.ParentUnderLyingId)+'>')
   FROM #UnderLyingConstituentMap T 
   INNER JOIN cte1 
   on t.UnderLyingId=cte1.ParentUnderLyingId
   WHERE Visited NOT LIKE ('%<'+convert(varchar(3),t.ParentUnderLyingId)+'>%')
 )
SELECT * FROM cte1
```